# Executing a bash command in an iOS app

Tags: ios, bash, command

Is it possible to execute a bash command within an iOS app? For example, I want to execute the "ping" command in my app, and I need to get the command's output as well. Hope I described my question correctly, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can but it is extremely limited, and ping will probably not work... Regardless use the system() and check gdb.

[Running BASH script from iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039207/running-bash-script-from-iphone-app)

But Quentin is right about using PING.

NOTE: This is only useful for debugging and shouldn't be used for actual apps.

This screenshot shows ls being run in the ios simulator through the C function system().
[image: This shows ls being ran in ios simulator.]

Comment: Oh, that's too bad... I want to write a console app for those who want to lean unix command in iOS... Thank you very much!

Comment: @Hang You could compile ping using this source... http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/inetutils/inetutils/ping/ping.c

Comment: Thanks @Mark ! I know I could, but maybe I need to add the bash to my project as well:(

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to execute a bash command within an iOS app?

As far as I know, bash isn't installed on iOS by default, so you would need to include a copy of bash in your application.

> For example, I want to execute the "ping" command in my app, and I need to get the command's output as well.

`ping` isn't a [bash command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html). It is a separate application. Apple have a [guide to writing ping functionality for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Thanks Quentin! Maybe I need to describe it more clearly: I want to write a small console app to accept user's input, such as "ls -a", "cp XX XX", "ps -aux" and redirect the command's output to the user interface. I know it's pretty easy to implement this in Mac OS, but I don't know how to realize it in iOS:(